# Can't get DATE format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes, sql-loader

I have database in access with a text field '1000306' - it is reporting date. I created table:

```
create table TT
(
DT VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

I loaded data by sql loader.

How can I get date from it? Should I convert varchar2 to DATE in Oracle? Or should I do it before loading data?

I tried:

```
create table TT
(
DT DATE
);
```

but it didnt load any data.

Comment: *"it didnt load any data."* So what messages did Loader write in the log file? Looking at that would surely be a useful exercise?

Comment: it shows: Commit point reached - logical record count 65
And then there is nothing in my table. But when I load it the same way, but choose datatype: varchar2 it loads without any issue.

Comment: What sort of date is `'1000306'`??? tenth of March 2006? sixth of March 2010? third of October 1906? Storing dates without a century or other formatting is just a recipe for data corruption.

Comment: The only formula I can think that gives a reasonable date is if it represents hours since 1st January 1900, so 1000306 gives 11 Feb 2014 10:00. Am I close?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, that column should have the DATE datatype.

Control file (used by SQL*Loader) should then convert input value into a valid date format, using the TO_DATE function, such as

```
load data
infile ...
fields ...
( ...
  dt "to_date(:dt, 'yyyymmdd')",    --> this
)
```

I don't know what date value you mentioned (1000306) represents (but I'm sure you do) so - just modify date format and, hopefully, you'll manage to load data.

As of your success when loading it into a VARCHAR2 column - no wonder, as it accepts any string (which 1000306 is), but you should **NOT** store date values into VARCHAR2 column, ever.